# Function that takes n rows as input and returns column names if sum in column equals n

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I have a large `DataFrame` that structures as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name1': [1, 0, 1,1],
                   'name2': [0, 0, 0,1],
                   'name3': [1, 1, 1,1],
                   'namen': [0, 0, 0,0]},
                  index=['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'labeln'])
>>> df
      name1 name2 name3 name4
label1  1     0     1      1
label2  0     0     0      1
label3  1     1     1      1
label4  0     0     0      0
```

I am trying to build a function that takes in **n** row names as arguments sums up the values in all columns and returns me the column names if the sum of those columns equals **n**.

For instance, using label1, label2 and label3 as inputs I would like to obtain the following output:

```py
def common_terms(*nargs):
   the function...

>>> common_terms(label1, label2, label3)
(name4)
```

or

```
>>> common_terms(label1, label3)
(name1, name3)
```

I have little knowledge of building functions in Python, but got my head really stuck on this. Could you kindly help me to progress?

Comment: Give example of your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter rows by `loc` and test if all `1` per columns, then filter `index` of `Series`:

```
def common_terms(*nargs):
   i = df.loc[list(nargs)].all()
   return i.index[i].tolist()

print (common_terms('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))
['namen']

print (common_terms('label1','label3'))
['name1', 'namen']
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted and so elegant and short. Thank you very much!